# SilverStripe - sum() a limited list of dataobject variables

Tags: php, silverstripe

In SilverStripe I want to calculate the sum of only the first three `DataObjects`, to get a sub amount.

I tried the following but the function always returns the sum of all `DataObjects` and not only the first three.

```
public function getSubSum() {
    $service = ServiceProvided::get()->filter(array(
        'InvoiceObjectID' => $this->ID
    ));
    $sum = $service->limit(3, 0)->sum('Sum');
    return $sum;
}
```

How do I calculate the sum of only the first three `DataObjects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the sum in PHP use a for loop to go through each database row returned, and add the value to a variable.

```
public function getSubSum() {

    $services = ServiceProvided::get()
        ->filter('InvoiceObjectID', $this->ID)
        ->limit(3, 0);

    $sum = 0;

    foreach($services as $service) {
        $sum += $service->Sum;
    };

    return $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The SUM is calculated first, and and then the limit is applied *after* the aggregate sum function has already been calculated. In effect you're asking it to calculate the sum first, which returns a single row, and then limit that result to three rows.

To do this you will probably need to use a subquery like:

```
SELECT SUM("Sum") FROM (SELECT "Sum" FROM "ServiceProvided" WHERE ... LIMIT 3)
```

To execute custom SQL in SilverStripe you can use `DB::query()`. However, you need to be careful when doing this to avoid SQL injection. A simpler approach would just be to calculate the sum in PHP.

Comment: hi, thx, can you tell me how to do it with php? how to get only the filtered and limited variables

Comment: I suggest you read an introduction to PHP and/or the SilverStripe documentation.